# comparing rows in the same table

Tags: mysql

```
id      Status      Material    Week
-------------------------------------
a1      Clear       iron        33
a1      Clear       iron        34
a1      Shipped     iron        35
b1      Cancel      Brass       33
b1      Cancel      Brass       34
b1      Cancel      Brass       35
c1      Identify    Plastic     34
c1      Clear       Plastic     35
```

Hello, I am trying to come up with a query where I can pick all those IDs whose Status or Material have changed between week 34 and week 35. If anything changed between week 33 and 34 or 33 and 35, ignore it. Also if anything which is not present in week 33 or 34 but present in week 35, it has to be included. At the end the ID should be unique.

So far I have come up with the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.Status<>t2.Status or t1.Material<>t2.Material
```

Expected result:

```
id
a1
c1
```

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: Expected result is

a1 and c1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT 
 T1.id
FROM t T1
LEFT JOIN t T2 ON T1.id = T2.id  
AND T2.Week = 34 
WHERE T1.Week = 35
AND IF(T2.id IS NULL, TRUE, ((T1.Status <> T2.status) OR (T1.Material <> T2.Material)))
```

<kbd>[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e3947/1/0)</kbd>

---

Just take two instances `T1 (row for week #35)` and `T2 (row for week #34)`

```
T2.week = 34

T1.week = 35
```

And if row of **week #34** exists then either the `status` or the `material` of `T1` and `T2` must differ in order to appear in the output.  <sub>Refer to the `IF` statement in the above query</sub>

---

**Test:**

```
create table t(
  id varchar(10),
  Status varchar(10),
  Material varchar(10),
  week int
  );

INSERT INTO t(id,status,material,week)
VALUES('a1','clear','iron',33),
('a1','clear','iron',34),
('a1','shipped','iron',35),
('b1','cancel','brass',33),
('b1','cancel','brass',34),
('b1','cancel','brass',35),
('c1','identify','plastic',34),
('c1','clear','plastic',35);
```

**Output:**

```
id
a1
c1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use  the count  (if the row change you have more then a row by id)

```
select t.id from (
   select distinct id, status, material 
   from mytable 
   where week in (33,34,35) ) t
group by t.id 
having count(*) >1;
```

eventually if the week is string try using

```
select t.id from (
   select distinct id, status, material 
   from mytable 
   where week in ('33','34','35') ) t
group by t.id 
having count(*) >1;
```

Comment: This query is not working for me at all. It says id is unknown column despite me having the id column in the table.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your query gives only those IDs which are common. Remember I need those IDs also which were inserted with week 35 but not present in week 33 and 34 also.

Answer (score 0):

The last part of this puzzle has been left as an exercise for the reader...

```
SELECT x.*, y.*
  FROM my_table x
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.id = x.id
   AND (y.status = x.status AND y.material = x.material)
   AND y.week = 35
 WHERE x.week = 34;
```